# Какая есть разница в работе docker-контейнеров и локального сервера OpenServer

Tags: laravel, vue.js, docker

Суть проблемы (я дилетант если что): делаю приложение (по урокам в свободном доступе) на Vue, Laravel, Sanctum. Когда запускаю его на OpenServer, то всё прекрасно работает. И авторизация и регистрация, добавление инф-и в базу и т.д.

Проблемы начинаются когда использую docker-контейнеры (ngix, php-fpm, node, mysql). Контейнеры поднимаются всё ок.
Страница сайта открывается, но дальше начинается свистопляска:

- при авторизации и регистрации вылетает 401 ошибка и всё дальше соответственно ничего не происходит. Приложение не пускает "ноунеймов" тут всё правильно. Вроде нашёл зацепку - localStorage с нужными данными для входа как-то самоликвидируется при переходе по ссылке, редиректе или обновлении страницы. Не могу понять из-за чего. (Это, наверное, основная проблема).
- Вот тоже одна из проблем как пример. До запуска db:seed данные получается добавить в БД, но если использовать db:seed, то всё тоже "хана" наступает - ничего не добавляется в базу.

Есть наверное и другие ну да ладно.

Самое непонятное, если снова запускаю тот же проект на OpenServer - всё ок, пашет.
Пробовал указывать docker-compose.yml один network у всех контейнеров - не помогло. Он по умолчанию и так кажется на один садится.

Можете подсказать как так с docker - не пашет, а на локалке - норм? В чём разница? Или наводку дать хотя бы?

Comment: Вероятнее всего, у вас проблемы с правами файлов внутри контейнера.